# OnClick Event Triggered on button click and Division, that button is inside that DIV

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am new to Javascript event handling, today I have encountered an issue for click event,

```
<div class="col-md-12" onclick='editField(1,1);'>
   <label></label>
   some more stufff
   <button onclick='remove(1,1);'>remove</button>
</div>
```

Now, When I click on the button, the remove functions called then the editField function too. I know why it called...

I want to prevent the editField function when the button gets clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use [stopPropagation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp)